# Customize Image referred From Html string

Tags: java, android, html, image

One of my project activities including long text written in string.xml  ,i add some images from resource within textview ,as after each phrase there is image then next the text phrase then image and so on ,

i getting that images from string  using this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView htmlTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day_tv);
        htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day), new ImageGetter(), null));
    }

    private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            int id = 0;
            if (source.equals("image1.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.a;
            } else if (source.equals("image2.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.b;
            } else if (source.equals("image3.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.c;
            } else if (source.equals("image4.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.d;
            } else if (source.equals("image5.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.e;
            }

            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        }
    };

}
```

and writing html img tag in string.xml as:

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

i want to be able to **customize each image** by changing its width and height or refer it to drawable style to add border around images for example  .

i tried using the bellow code foe changing width and height :

```
<img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="150">
```

but it doesn't work .

any advice to achieve that will be appreciated , thanks .

Comment: What is it that isn't working? For me it's really hard to understand your question - perhaps I'm not the only one, since no one has bothered to comment your question or give you an answer. Maybe you should try to re-phrase your question.
What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why are you putting html inside `TextViews`?

Comment: @Darwind i edit the post , please check it

Comment: for each image do you want to set a different width and height?

Comment: @blackbelt yes my dear for each image different width and height ,thanks

Comment: and the width/height are different from the one of the drawable?

Comment: @blackbelt yes my dear

Comment: I am doing something similar. I need to get my captcha image from a website. I get the source code and now I want to extract the image. I have implemented to same image getter but i get an error on the line `id = R.drawable.a;` stating `a cannot be resolved to a type`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I finally  end up to this solution which allow to **change width and height for each image** but still one point not achieved which is **referring image to drawable shape as background** , 
still work on it   :

```
 private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        int id,id1,id2,id3,id4 = 0;

        if (source.equals("image1.jpg")) {
            id = R.drawable.a;
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 20);
         return d;
         }           
        else if (source.equals("image2.jpg")) {
            id1 = R.drawable.b;
            Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(id1);
            d1.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 40);
         return d1;
         }           
        else if (source.equals("image3.jpg")) {
            id2 = R.drawable.c;
            Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(id2);
            d2.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 60);
         return d2; 
         }          
         else if (source.equals("image4.jpg")) {
            id3 = R.drawable.d;                      
            Drawable d3 = getResources().getDrawable(id3);
            d3.setBounds(0, 0, 140, 80);           
        return d3;
         }
         else if (source.equals("image5.jpg")) {
             id4 = R.drawable.e;                      
             Drawable d4 = getResources().getDrawable(id4);
             d4.setBounds(0, 0, 160, 100);            
         return d4;
     }
        return null;
       };
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `Html.fromHtml()`, which supports only a [very limited set of tags and attributes](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html). `<img>` is supported, but setting the width and height of the image is not. It's possible to achieve it with a `TextView` (by using `SpannableString` and `ImageSpan`), but it's more complicated and not very flexible.

Instead, you should use a `WebView` which handles HTML properly.

It's easy to load a string :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.loadData(getResources(R.string.day), "text/html", null);
```

You can find more examples [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

---

Just for comparison, here is an example without using a `WebView` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello :)");

    // Draw the image with a size of 50x50
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy_face);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

    // Replace the ":)" in the string by our drawable
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 6, 8, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
}
```

It will load much faster, but you can't use HTML.

Comment: in the beginning of my project i tried using webview instead of textview but i found textview with html tags easier as i wasn't familiar that time with webview , my text too long and already done with customization in string.xml  , if there is no other way so i have to restart with webview , thanks my dear

Comment: please cant we customize image inside ImageGetter class for each one , thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, although I'm not 100% sure that it will work.

Comment: it gave me force close ( java.lang.RuntimeException)and error show to this line :         htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day), new ImageGetter(), null));

Comment: Do you have more details about this error? But you should really go for a `WebView` if you want to add additional styles to your images later (borders, ...)

Comment: i regard that finally but now im trying  to achieve that with textview and html ,i will upload the logcat error , thanks